# Validate an AMQConnection connection string without connecting?

Tags: java, amqp, qpid

The Apache Qpid Java client API has an [AMQConnection](http://people.apache.org/~grkvlt/qpid-site/qpid-java/qpid-client/apidocs/org/apache/qpid/client/AMQConnection.html) class that is used to make a connection to a Qpid message broker. I'm using the single-String constructor (`AMQConnection(String connection)`). I have a utility method that creates the connection string first, which is then passed to the AMQConnection constructor.

The connection string is of the form `amqp://<username>:<password>@<clientID>/?brokerlist='tcp://<hostname>:<port>'`.

If the constructor is passed a connection string with incorrect syntax, it throws a `URLSyntaxException`.

I would like to move the connection string syntax check to the utility method (I'm of the opinion that it shouldn't be able to return broken information), but I have not found any way of validating the connection string short of trying to set up a connection to the message broker. Is there any way of doing this, or do I just have to rely on the `URLSyntaxException` being thrown from the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only want to check the URI for correct syntax? If so, simply create an instance of [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class:

```
new URI("amqp://user:pwd@42/?brokerlist='tcp://example.com:80'")
```

This throws an `java.net.URISyntaxException` when URI is not syntactically correct.

If you need to check the URI for AMQ-specific options, you might have two have a look at AMQ source code and find a class that validates/parses this.